# Компоненты во Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

разрабатывай SPA приложение при помощи Vue.js, сейчас занимаюсь комнатой администратора. Она содержит в себе 4-5 вкладок (страниц). Конечно же я все эти вкладки разделили на разные компоненты но они получились по 300 строк кода (150 - HTML, Vue - 100, CSS - 50). Вопрос заключается в следующем... Каждая вкладка содержит в себе 1-5 различных форм, может быть их тоже разделит на разные компоненты и собирать их все во вкладке? Либо с этим не нужно заморачиваться?

Answer (score 2):

Если все поля формы имеют схожие стили, то лучше 1 поле формы сделать как отдельный компонент.

Создайте компонент `text-field.vue` и поместите в него это:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</template>

<style>
input {
  /*STYLES FOR INPUT*/
}
</style>
```

И затем подключите этот компонент в свои `admin.vue` и спокойно используйте его.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <TextField></TextField>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TextField from 'text-field.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    TextField
  }
}
</script>
```